# (Python) I cannot for the life of me understand Scopes and why the variables in them aren't being transferred to the main()

Tags: python-3.x

I'm writing a Days Calculator and I'm having an issue with getting my variables inside my function to be read outside of them.

I want the userInput() function to take userInput for the dates. if I put everything under:
#-=-=Varibles-=-=

then it works.

but even tho I'm calling the userInput() scope in the main() scope, idle states that the variable doesn't exist and throws an exception.

```
# Python3 program to find number of days
# between two given dates
from datetime import date

def ask_user(Question):
    VALID = 1
    while VALID == 1:
        try:
            response = int(input(Question))
        except ValueError as e:
            print("\nNOT A VALID ENTRY, TRY AGAIN\n")
            VALID = 1
        else:
            break
    return response
 
def numOfDays(date1, date2):
    return (date2-date1).days

def userInput():
    year1  = ask_user("Enter the year of the first date(yyyy): ")
    month1 = ask_user("Enter the Month of the first date: ")
    day1   = ask_user("Enter the Day of the first date: ")
    print("now the second date")
    year2  = ask_user("Enter the yeay of the second date(yyyy): ")
    month2 = ask_user("Enter the month of the second date: ")
    day2   = ask_user("Enter the Day of the second date: ")
    # print(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2)
    return year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2

def calaMath():
    # calculations
    date1 = date(year1, month1, day1)
    date2 = date(year2, month2, day2)
    print(numOfDays(date1, date2), "days")

def main():
    userInput()
    calaMath()

#=-=-=-=-Varibles-=-=-=-=-


main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function are like a black box, nothing outside of it can see what is inside, only its output, aka what is returned, to make use of that you need to assign it to a variable (usually) and then work on that, otherwise those are discarded.

The problem here is that you effectively discarded the result of `userInput` in your main function by not saving it inside some variable and give it to `calaMath` to do its thing.

You have it right with your `ask_user` function and how you use it.

There are 2 simply ways to fix it

Capture the result of userInput and give it to calaMath

```
def main():
   year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2 = userInput()
   calaMath(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2)
```

and of course change calaMath accordingly

```
def calaMath(year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2):
    #the rest stay the same
```

the other simple fix is simple make the call to userInput inside of calaMath

```
def calaMath():
   year1,month1,day1,year2,month2,day2 = userInput()
   #the res stay the same
```

and change main accordingly

```
def main():
    calaMath()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this def clears up the confusion I had about user functions! much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use local variables declared inside userInput() after they are out of scope. One solution would be to declare all variables globally, but that's not a best practice.

Use the return values from userInput() and pass those into calaMath().

Regarding scope: each set of variables is only visible in the function where they are declared.

- Inside userInput() you can use year1, month1, day1, year2, month2,
  and day2.
- Inside calaMath() you can use yr1, mn1, dy1, yr2, mn2, and dy2.
- Inside main() you can use y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, and d2.

```
def userInput():
    year1  = ask_user("Enter the year of the first date(yyyy): ")
    month1 = ask_user("Enter the month of the first date: ")
    day1   = ask_user("Enter the day of the first date: ")
    print("Now the second date")
    year2  = ask_user("Enter the year of the second date(yyyy): ")
    month2 = ask_user("Enter the month of the second date: ")
    day2   = ask_user("Enter the day of the second date: ")
    return year1, month1, day1, year2, month2, day2

def calaMath(yr1, mn1, dy1, yr2, mn2, dy2):
    date1 = date(yr1, mn1, dy1)
    date2 = date(yr2, mn2, dy2)
    print(numOfDays(date1, date2), "days")

def main():
    y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2 = userInput()
    calaMath(y1, m1, d1, y2, m2, d2)
```

Comment: Ok I def have a hard time understanding how to use arguments in scopes but this cleared it up for me somewhat. thanks!